# Output a @Transient String value in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have a basic getter/setter in a POJO, the value for which I am displaying on a JSP using Thymeleaf via Hibernate.

`<span class="myClass" th:text="${myClause}">clause here</span>`

The value prints just fine for a run-of-the-mill getter/setter but when I introduce the `@Transient` annotation on `myClause`, the value doesn't print.

Is this a limitation with Thymeleaf?  Do I need to persist the value for it to evaluate?

I am using Thymeleaf 2.1.4.RELEASE.

Comment: transient means you are disabling serialization. I do not think this would be a limitation on Thymeleaf part. And thus in the end disallowing it to be passed on

Comment: Right - so any idea why the value would not print?

Comment: Can you output the variable to console from controller to see if it is populated?

Comment: that is before you pass it on to jsp request

Comment: Yes.  I wound up persisting as a workaround.  Still an issue in Thymeleaf 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After forking a Thymeleaf sample and trying it, I noticed that transient values are shown correctly.  There is no issue with the Thymeleaf code.  My error was because I did not also annotate the setter with `@Transient`.  (In the project, we are explicitly setting properties on the context.)